# Kill the process and restart server when memory is exceeded - bash and cron

Tags: linux, bash, memory, cpu, limit

I have a site on webfaction, using django and python.

However, I have problem with memory.

The problem arises, because I use external library, that can run forever (consuming much time and memory).

I tried to limit execution time (using threads), but it appeared that nothing worked in multithreaded envorinment.

As a last way, I'm trying to write bash script file (run by cron), that will kill all processes and restart the server if memory used is more than 300 MB.

Another problem is that I don't know bash.

Could someone help me to write a bash script that will perform above mentioned site?

I think it will be fairly short.

OS is Linux.

Thank you.

Comment: You can write it in python just as well, cron doesn't really care :)

Comment: That's the problem. I didn't find a way to kill the process using pure python. If I found, I wouldn't need cron. I just run it from within django.

Comment: Maybe you should ask that question instead :) But there's a twist if you want to run it from django and the process to kill is not running under the same userid as django - you'd need to run django as root which is not a good practice. But you can run a tiny standalone python script in root's cron.

Comment: os.system("kill -9 %s" % pid_to_kill)

Comment: As I was explained this doesn't work under mod_wsgi. Is there anyway to write bash script?

Comment: But it does work in a python script invoked via cron, no?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know pid. I need to kill all processes and restart server. Also, I don't know how to check memory from python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24269/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-andrew-fount).

Comment: I responded to your code.

Comment: you can do a simple script with for-loop script to kill all the services and perform a reboot